# Excel 2010 formula needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a complicated formula in Excel 2010. In a worksheet named “Availability” I want to put a number in Column “A” from 1-6000. I want it to search on worksheet “Main” Column “A” for the number I entered, and return the value of Column “D” of the line that the number I entered is found on to column “D” on the “Availability” worksheet.
An example is I enter the number 1259 on worksheet “Availability” in cell “A3” , the formula will look in worksheet “Main” Column “A”  for that number, and return the value of Column “D” on the line that 1259 is found on and put the value in column “D” of the “Availability” worksheet.
I hope I have made it clear.

Comment: If your Column A values (1-6000) are in sequential order, you can use the INDEX() function. Or you can use the VLOOKUP() function whether the vales are sorted or not.

Comment: You may use Lookup formula either VLOOKUP or combination of INDEX & MATCH,, [for better understanding check this link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/02/12/vlookup-multiple-sheets-excel-examples/) ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Main!A:D,4,FALSE)
```

[image]

If you need more help, you can give a sample and provide more information about your problem.